# jQuery to position menu according to window width

Tags: jquery, menu, window, width

I'm trying to use a little bit of jQuery to move my menu depending on the width of the screen.

The problem is that it's fine above a certain window width (1140px) but, part of the menu is obscured at other widths. I have a media query that displays the menu at 980px, so between 980 and 1140 I need a different position for the menu.

I have this so far;

```
$(window).width(function(){
    var win = 1140px;
    if(window.width<=win){
        $("nav ul").css("left", "45%");}
    else {
       $("nav ul").css("left", "55%");}
});
```

This isn't working and I know it's a basic mistake, but I'm not experienced enough to write this kind of code off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function resize(){
  var win = 1140;
  if ($(window).width() <= win) { 
    $("nav ul").css("left", "45%");
  } else {
    $("nav ul").css("left", "55%");
  }
};
resize();
$(window).on('resize', resize);
```

Based on the answer from @user86745458

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

```
function resize(){
  var win = 1140px;
  if ($(window).width() <= win) { 
    $("nav ul").css("left", "45%");
  } else {
    $("nav ul").css("left", "55%");
  }
});
resize();
$(window).on('resize', resize);
```

Comment: I actually don't need the script now as I've changed the menu and it's smaller, so it fits better. But there was a minor error here; I kept getting an "Unexpected Token". It was the closing parenthesis on the third last line. Otherwise it's a good one though. If you could quickly fix it, I'll mark it as the answer @user86745458

Comment: Please change if ($(window).width() <= win) to if ($(window).width() <= 1140). or simply change var win = 1140px to var win = 1140. It should work. Thanks.